# Can someone give me clue where the mistake is

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get user input for a number and then write a name row by row in linux terminal that much amount of times that user inputed. Example if I lets say chose a number 2 the program will write Name 2 times row by row. I wrote some code but I cant figure where is the mistake. I think its the loop where the mistake is.

```
echo "Please enter a number "
read $number

for value in {$number}
do
echo "Name"
done
```

Comment: Even when you fix the issues with the variables, `for value in $n` is not going to iterate from 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

To read input and save it into a variable named `number`, do:

```
read number
```

To get the value of number, do `$number` or `${number}`. Remove the `{` `}` in the `{$number}` or shift `$` with `{`.

Comment: Thank you soo much now the program asks for a number I enter the value but it isnt displaying any of tekst that said names

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
echo "Please enter a number "
read number
if ! test "$number" -gt 0 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "You must enter an integer greater than 0" >&2
    exit 1
fi
yes Name | sed ${number}q
```

But don't prompt for the number.  Take it as a command line argument, and just do

```
yes Name | sed "${1}q"
```

Let sed generate the error message if the parameter is invalid.

The trouble with your loop is that `for value in $number` takes the string `$number` and breaks it on whitespace (depends on IFS, actually, but let's not get bogged down by details) and iterates over each value.  That is, if `$number` is the string `1 3 dog 5`, then the loop will iterate 4 times with `$value` taking the values `1`, `3`, `dog`, and `5`.  If `$number` is `7`, then the loop iterates exactly once.   You could do `for((i=0; i < $number; i++)); do ...`, but that does not generate any useful error message if $number is not an integer.

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH the code works now I get what I didnt do right I was telling my code to read the number value but never to print that amount of times. THANK YOU